# Have Anyone used the Magento Extension "Improved Import"?

Tags: php, magento

I want to ask a question to the fellow developers.
Has anyone used the Magento Extension "[Improved Import](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/improved-import.html)"?

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/improved-import.html

**Questions:**

1. I am running the Magento version 1.9.2.2. Is it compatible with this extension?
2. I want to import product images from a third party URL. Is it the best extension for this purpose?

Please suggest if you have alternative options.

Comment: Hello! Our Extension always works great on last version of Magento 1.x. Also Magento 2 version is available -  https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

Answer (score 0):

Which features of Improved Import do you need?

[Magmi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) is powerful, fast, and free. I have used it quite a few times successfully.